# HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child

Tags: java, android

I ve got a relative Layout and adding imageview programatically in my horizontal scrollview which is placed in xml.when i tried to add my imageview in horizontalScrollView ..i m getting the runtime exception .HorizontalScrollView can host only a single child.could you guys help me out

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams HParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        HParams.topMargin = 200 * displayHeight / 480;
        HsrollView.setLayoutParams(HParams);

         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
             ImageView btnTag = new ImageView(this);
             btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             btnTag.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
             btnTag.setTag(i);
             btnTag.setId(i);
             HsrollView.addView(btnTag);
         }
```

**XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/directbg"
    tools:context=".DirectorActivity" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Hscrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meaning, you have to add the imageview to the linearlayout. when you add the image view you are adding it to the `HorizontalScrollview` which also has a `LinearLayout` in it ther by adding 2 child elements to the HorizontalScrollView which you cannot do

Answer (score 3):

You should be adding your buttons to your `LinearLayout`, not directly to the `HorizontalScrollView`. As the error indicates, a `HorizontalScrollView` can only have one child.

The best way to do this would be to give your `LinearLayout` an ID, and reference the `LinearLayout` in your code instead of the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you everything you need.  A `ScrollView` can only have one child and in your layout xml you already have a `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` so you just need to add your images to the `LinearLayout` instead of the `ScrollView`.